# Basic dice game with minor error... tells you you win and lose when you roll doubles

Tags: python

As stated in the question, I wrote this for class for a basic dice game. You either roll doubles or the two dice add to 7 or 11 and you win. Oddly enough, the way I wrote it causes it to say you win and lose when you roll a double that adds up below 10. I know it's silly but I barely understand python as is and burned myself getting this far...

```
import random

while input:
    print ('Take a chance and roll the dice!')
    print ('(Press enter to roll!)')
    input ()
    dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
    roll = int(dice1) + int(dice2)
    print ('You rolled a', dice1, 'and a', dice2, '. Your total is', dice1 + dice2)

    if dice1 == dice2:
        print ('Well done, you rolled a double, you win!')

    if roll == 7 or roll == 11:
        print('You win!')

    elif roll == 3 or roll == 4 or roll == 5 or roll == 6 or roll == 8 or roll == 9 or roll == 10:
        print ('Dang, you lose!')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It enters both `if` statements right now. You need to change the second `if` to `elif`.

```
elif roll == 7 or roll == 11:
    print('You win!')
```

Besides that, it'd look better if you refactor the last `if` statement as follows:

```
elif roll in range(3, 11): # 7 is in the list but, doesn't matter
    print ('Dang, you lose!')
```

Comment: Holy cow I feel dumb... Thank you so much! XD

Comment: Oh yeah sorry X3 never used this before. :3 one sec!

Comment: @PaigeZater: That last `elif` doesn't actually need a condition, since if you don't win you lose. So it could just be `elif:` `print ('Dang, you lose!')`

Comment: That is right @PM2Ring. The last `elif` is totally unnecessary and can be safely converted to `else`

Comment: Oh, cool ^w^ I already submitted it but I'll have to remember to not write so much and try to keep it as simple as possible X3 Thank you ^w^

Comment: @ozgurv: Yeah, that's what I meant to write. :blush:

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting

```
elif roll in range(3, 11): 
    print ('Dang, you lose!')
```

You could try

```
if roll != 7 or roll != 11:
    print('Dang, you lose!')
```

Sorry mate, I meant to put that.

Comment: That's exactly the same answer that was given half a year ago... Please focus on a more current question next time ;)